# How to draw 2D pixel-by-pixel in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, 2d

I'm trying to draw on the screen pixel-by-pixel using XNA, but am having problems with resources.  I thought the best way would be to have 1 texture that updates every frame, but I'm having trouble updating it.  Here's what I've got so far, just as a test:

```
Texture2D canvas;
Rectangle tracedSize;
UInt32[] pixels;

protected override void Initialize()
    {
        tracedSize = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.Bounds;
        canvas = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, tracedSize.Width, tracedSize.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
        pixels = new UInt32[tracedSize.Width * tracedSize.Height];               

        base.Initialize();
    }

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        pixels[100] = 0xFF00FF00;
        canvas.SetData<UInt32>(pixels, 0, tracedSize.Width * tracedSize.Height);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(canvas, new Rectangle(0, 0, tracedSize.Width, tracedSize.Height), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

When Draw() is called the second time, I get the following error:

"The operation was aborted. You may not modify a resource that has been set on a device, or after it has been used within a tiling bracket."

If I try to make a new Texture2D in Draw(), I quickly get an out of memory error.  This is for Windows Phone.  It seems like I'm trying to do it the wrong way, what other options do I have to make it work?

Comment: I didn't know the answer so I googled "xna procedural texture" (which is what this sort of thing is called). There doesn't seem to be a simple, built-in way to do this. There are at least three common suggestions (buffering, GPU texture commands, doing it in a shader). The last is obviously optimal, but requires shader programming knowledge. You might want to perform the same search and browse what's out there.

Comment: For people looking to draw on the fly pixel-by-pixel 2D textures, it has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70022699/how-to-draw-on-the-fly-2d-pixel-by-pixel-in-monogame-xna

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting `GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null` before you call SetData. Depending on the effect you're after there may be a more performant method, you could also consider Silverlights WriteableBitmap.

Edit: This is the code I tested in the emulator:

```
Texture2D canvas;
Rectangle tracedSize;
UInt32[] pixels;

protected override void Initialize()
{
    tracedSize = GraphicsDevice.PresentationParameters.Bounds;
    canvas = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, tracedSize.Width, tracedSize.Height, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
    pixels = new UInt32[tracedSize.Width * tracedSize.Height];

    base.Initialize();
}
Random rnd = new Random();
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

    GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null;
    pixels[rnd.Next(pixels.Length)] = 0xFF00FF00;
    canvas.SetData<UInt32>(pixels, 0, tracedSize.Width * tracedSize.Height);

    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(canvas, new Rectangle(0, 0, tracedSize.Width, tracedSize.Height), Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();

    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I got it to work from your example. I think the first time I tried it I may have been newing a Texture2D in Draw().

Answer (score 3):

You basically need to do as it asks in the exception:

To ensure that the texture is not set on the graphics device, put this at the end of `Draw`:

```
GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null;
```

To ensure you are not drawing inside a tiling bracket, do not use `SetData` inside of `Draw` at all. Move the call to `SetData` into `Update`.

---

Bonus info: Your out-of-memory error is because you are not releasing the unmanaged resources that `Texture2D` allocates (the garbage collector can't track them, so it doesn't know you're running out of memory). You need to call `Dispose` on the texture. However making a new texture each frame is a bad idea anyway (there's no way to avoid the performance and memory fragmentation problems it causes).

Answer (score 1):

**Never create or modify a texture in** `Draw()` ** ever.**

The SpriteBatch.Draw() call expects the GraphicsDevice buffer to contain all of the texture data (by extension to the GPU buffer), any changes still happening(from Update and IsRunningSlowly == true) at this point will cause tearing when rendered.

The workaround of `GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null;` blocks the Draw call and the game until transfer to the GPU is complete, thus slowing the entire game loop.

Reuse a Texure2D object declared at the class level.