# c# XNA render a given section of a 2D bool array representing a 2 color image to the window

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, rendering, boolean

Firstly, is my logic about how much space this array will take up correct?

```
bool[,] b = new bool[8192 /* 8 * 1024 = 1KB */, 20]; // 20KB
```

I wish to render a given section of a 2D array to the window. The array is of bools and represents a 2 color image. The image should take up the whole window and each pixel should be sharp\pixelated as opposed to there being interpolation\gradients between the pixels centers.

For example (there will ofc be more encapsulation than this):

```
draw(bool[,] b,
float top_left_x, float top_left_y, float width, float height,
float false_red, float false_green, float false_blue,
float true_red, float true_green, float true_blue)
{
    // what goes here?
}
```

Is there anything build into c#\XNA to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the same thing as opposed here: [How to draw 2D pixel-by-pixel in XNA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837471/how-to-draw-2d-pixel-by-pixel-in-xna)

The only thing you have to do is check which color will get into your texture for if it is true or false.

Comment: True. it is not the fastest solution. You could also just store you data in a [`RenderTarget2D`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rendertarget2d.rendertarget2d.aspx) and use that as your data source instead of bools.

Comment: Do all solutions involve storing an int32 for each value?

Comment: Probably yes, the `SurfaceFormat.Single` seems to be the cheapest one around. You could always consider building the texture every frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Texture2D, and then use the SetData function with a array of colors. I haven't tested it, but it should work.