# How to draw on the fly 2D pixel-by-pixel in MonoGame/XNA?

Tags: xna, draw, pixel, monogame, texture2d

I was wondering **how to draw on the fly pixel by pixel** in XNA/MonoGame and could only find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837471/how-to-draw-2d-pixel-by-pixel-in-xna). Problem is, the question wasn't centered about how to actually draw pixel by pixel but rather manage resources and updating stuff.

Because I couldn't find any simple and short answer and was wondering how to do for some time now, I'll share a snippet I stumbled upon (see answer).

*NB: If anyone having a better approach or an alternative method to do it, feel free to post or comment!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a class level variable for your texture and sizes:

```
Texture2D Tex, Tex1, Tex2;
const int WIDTH = 32;
const int HEIGHT = 32;
Color[] TexSource = new Color[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
```

Initialize the variables in `LoadContent()`

```
int radius = 5;
point center = new Point(WIDTH >> 2, HEIGHT >> 2);
Tex = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
for(int x = 0 ; x < WIDTH; x++)
  for(int y = 0 ; y < HEIGHT; y++)
    if(Math.Sqrt((x - center.x)* (x - center.x)) < radius && Math.Sqrt((y - center.y) * (y - center.y) < radius))
       TexSource[x + y * WIDTH] = Color.Red;
    else
       TexSource[x + y * WIDTH] = Color.White;
  Tex = SetData<Color>(TexSource);    
  //The resulting texture is a red circle on a white background.

  //If you want to draw on top of an existing texture Tex1 as Tex2:
  Tex1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>(Tex1Name);
  Tex2 = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, Tex1.Width, Tex1.Height);
  TexSource = Tex1.GetData<Color>();
  // Draw a white \ on the image, we will assume tex1 is square for this task
  for(int x = 0 ; x < Tex1.Width; x++)
    for(int y = 0 ; y < Tex1.Width; y++)
       if(x==y) TexSource[x + y * Tex1.Width] = Color.White;
```

You may change the textures in `Update()`

**But, never create or modify a texture in** `Draw()` **ever.**

The `SpriteBatch.Draw()` call expects the `GraphicsDevice` buffer to contain all of the texture data (by extension to the GPU buffer), any changes still happening(from Update and `IsRunningSlowly` == true) at this point will cause tearing when rendered.

The workaround of `GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = null;` **blocks the Draw call and the game** until transfer to the GPU is complete, thus slowing the entire game loop.

Comment: I didn't know these things! Thank you for the in-depth answer

Comment: @atrefeu, you are welcome, just to clarify, a 1x1 image may lead to scaling artifacts depending on Blend Mode, and given the efficiency gains of transfer and storage to the GPU there would never be an advantage to using a texture with a size less than 4x4. (depends on many factors, foremost is SurfaceFormat), but larger sizes transfer faster, with less overhead, up to 256MB per PCIE cycle.This is why my answer uses 32x32.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `SetData()` method of a `Texture2D` object you previously initialized with a 1 by 1 size.

```
Texture2D pixel; //ie. in class declaration
```

And later, for instance in the Initialize method:

```
pixel = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
pixel.SetData(new Color[] {Color.White});
```

*Edit:*
As Strom mentionned in his answer, the Texture2D object must be declared at the class level. **You should avoid declaring or modifying a texture in the `Draw()` method** as it'll slow the game loop.