# How to draw a Texture2D sprite appear as if it's growing upwards out of another Texture2D? MonoGame/XNA

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I was wondering how to draw a Texture2D sprite to appear as if a vine is growing upwards, like in [Super Mario Bros](https://youtu.be/-Cuz39rP2cE?t=11). Are there any options to make this work?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837471/how-to-draw-2d-pixel-by-pixel-in-xna) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70022699/how-to-draw-on-the-fly-2d-pixel-by-pixel-in-monogame-xna) but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

I'm relatively new to game development so I'm not sure where to start. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to draw the full-length vine as one sprite, load it as a `Texture2D`, and then on each frame draw it at a different y-coordinate offset so it appears to move across the screen. Once you have a moving vine, you need to clip a portion of it so it appears to grow out of a reference point. You can achieve this by calculating the right coordinates for the `sourceRectangle` and `destinationRectangle` of the `SpriteBatch.Draw` method.